# Good ways to sort a sortedset when data is string date

Tags: java

The Sortedset can sort itself automatically but in some case, it doesn't work as I want. For example. I stored String date value in a sortedset but apparently it didn't work as my expectation. This is what I got:

```
[03-10-2013, 06-10-2013, 08-10-2013, 09-10-2013, 18-09-2013, 24-09-2013, 29-09-2013]
```

Is there any good way to deal with this problem without having to introduce a comparator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to avoid using String to represent a Date. Use a Date, which has a natural chronological order. Transform the date to a String only when necessary, i.e. to display it to users or store them in files.

The reason it doesn't work is that the natural ordering of String is the lexicographic order. So "18-09-2013" comes after "03-10-2013", simply because '1' comes after '0' in the lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set of either:

- Date objects `java.util.Date` or
- Time in milli seconds `java.lang.Integer`

These objects can be compared much easier.